# System MTU for SAN switch

Tags: networking, cisco, storage-area-network, ethernet, mtu

I have a SAN with redundant cisco 2960s when I set it up a while ago I set all of the interfaces to use an MTU of 9000. I was looking at the config today and I noticed this line `system mtu routing 1500` will that cause any problems? or because this is a switch everything should be fine because there isn't any routing.

Comment: I assume this is for iSCSI? Is jumbo frames enabled on the array and the servers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Peter, you can rest safe knowing that `system mtu routing 1500` only affects routed Vlans.